# Cannot have a qualifier in the select list while performing a JOIN w/ USING keyword

Tags: sql, join, using

I am looking at a practice test that doesn't have explanations about the correct answers. The question I'm confused about basically asks why the following SQL statement can never work:

```
SELECT oi.order_id, product_jd, order_date
FROM order_items oi JOIN orders o
USING(order_id);
```

The answer it gave was: "The statement would not execute because the column part of the USING clause cannot have a qualifier in the SELECT list"

Can someone elaborate on this? I am pretty stumped.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's complaining about the `oi` qualifier:

```
SELECT oi.order_id, product_jd, order_date
       ^^^
```

Oracle does not allow qualifiers in combination with a `using` join.  The clearest way out is using a regular join:

```
SELECT oi.order_id, product_jd, order_date
FROM order_items oi 
JOIN orders o ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
```

You can also omit the qualifier.  The `using` statement tells Oracle that even though there are two fields called `order_id`, they are both equal:

```
SELECT order_id, product_jd, order_date
FROM order_items oi JOIN orders o
USING(order_id)
```