# unable to group the data in ORACLE with GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, oracle, join, group-by

```
select offices.office_id,
count(staff_id)
from offices join  staffs using (office_id) join managers using (manager_id)
group by office_id;
```

I kept on getting

> ERROR at line 1: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier.

I am trying to count the total number of staffs in different offices. Here I have grouped the result by office id. What has gone wrong here.

but if I do like this

```
select count(staff_id)
from offices join  staffs using (office_id) join managers using (manager_id)
group by office_id;
```

it works this way and display only one column since I have removed `offices.office_id column`. But I need the office id with its corresponding number of staffs side by side in two columns.

Comment: use group by offices.office_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using the `USING` clause in a query, specifying table name is redundant. Only the column name is enough information for the database. For example - `select office_id`. Try this :

```
select office_id,
count(staff_id)
from offices join  staffs using (office_id) join managers using (manager_id)
group by office_id;
```

Refer to this similar question : [Cannot have a qualifier in the select list while performing a JOIN w/ USING keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890572/cannot-have-a-qualifier-in-the-select-list-while-performing-a-join-w-using-keyw)

Comment: [+1 Works](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af113/1), although `USING` should nowadays probably be converted to `ON` syntax.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson. Thanks for the SQL Fiddle link. :)

Comment: This worked. 
You said that specifying table name is redundant when querying. This pretty much explained everything to me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

office_id is common column accross tables. so you have to either specify alias or use tablename.columnname

Try this..

```
select offices.office_id,
count(staffs.staff_id)
from offices join  staffs on staffs.office_id=offices.office_id
join managers on managers.manager_id=staffs.manager_id
group by offices.office_id;
```

Comment: This won't work with the `USING` syntax, only with `ON`.

Comment: i have changed my query to ON which is ANSI standard

Comment: @user2760858 : see the latest edited answer. you should ensure that the join columns are correct as per your table ddl