# Column part cannot have quantifier in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have a schema and am trying to get distinct student id's
The sql I wrote makes sense, but Oracle says

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
```

The sql I wrote is

```
SQL> Select distinct Student.s_id
  2  from (Student join Takes using(s_id))
  3  join (Instructor join Teaches using(i_id))
  4  using (course_id, sec_id, semester, year)
  5  where instructor.name = 'evan';
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Cannot have a qualifier in the select list while performing a JOIN w/ USING keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890572/cannot-have-a-qualifier-in-the-select-list-while-performing-a-join-w-using-keyw)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the reference to `Student` in the `select`:

```
select distinct s_id
```

Comment: Thank you it worked